# Double dispatch in C#?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, language-features, double-dispatch

I have heard/read the term but don't quite understand what it means.

When should I use this technique and how would I use it? Can anyone provide a good code sample?

Comment: Currently this is the best way to do it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/curth/2008/11/15/c-dynamic-and-multiple-dispatch/

Comment: Great example of double dispatch at [Applying Object Composition to Build Rich Domain Models](https://vimeo.com/195774910).

Comment: [Beware of the double dispatch](https://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2010/04/19/double-dispatch-is-a-code-smell/). Probably you can avoid it for better code maintenance.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The visitor pattern is a way of doing double-dispatch in an object-oriented way.

It's useful for when you want to choose which method to use for a given argument based on its type at runtime rather than compile time.

Double dispatch is a special case of **multiple dispatch**.

When you call a virtual method on an object, that's considered single-dispatch because which actual method is called depends on the type of the single object.

For double dispatch, both the object's type and the method sole argument's type is taken into account. This is like method overload resolution, except that the argument type is determined at runtime in double-dispatch instead of statically at compile-time.

In multiple-dispatch, a method can have multiple arguments passed to it and which implementation is used depends on each argument's type. The order that the types are evaluated depends on the language. In LISP, it checks each type from first to last.

Languages with multiple dispatch make use of generic functions, which are just function delcarations and aren't like generic methods, which use type parameters.

**To do double-dispatch in C#**, you can declare a method with a sole object argument and then specific methods with specific types:

```
using System.Linq;  

class DoubleDispatch
{ 
    public T Foo<T>(object arg)
    { 
        var method = from m in GetType().GetMethods()
                   where    m.Name == "Foo" 
                         && m.GetParameters().Length==1
                         && arg.GetType().IsAssignableFrom
                                           (m.GetParameters()[0].GetType())
                         && m.ReturnType == typeof(T)
                   select m;

        return (T) method.Single().Invoke(this,new object[]{arg});          
    }

    public int Foo(int arg) { /* ... */ }

    static void Test() 
    { 
        object x = 5;
        Foo<int>(x); //should call Foo(int) via Foo<T>(object).
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful use of LINQ with reflection - I hadn't thought to apply it to those tedious xxxInfo objects before. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not so sure this is a great idea. This doesn't really implement double dispatch at all, I need to know *at compile-t* what the type of the thing is in order to specify the type parameter!! You may as well not bother with all the reflection code and simply cast the object. Am I missing something?

Comment: It does implement double dispatch in that it's dispatching on both the runtime type of the object (derived from DoubleDispatch) and the method argument. The reflection on return type is used for extending the machanism to subclasses, so you can add "string Foo(string)" to a subclass and it'll work.

Comment: Great example but I think you can enhance it further and add a subclass of DoubleDispatch and then call that subclass's method(Like the one you suggested in your previous comment). That will make the double-dispatching more apparent and easily understandable.

Comment: Given that we now have a _dynamic_ type in C#, this is only here for historical purposes. Feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: If double dispatch is explained using reflection, I think the example is not that great. As I think reflection is not required. I think an example should display the bare essence. Probably I just fail to see the issue that the double dispatch is solving.

Comment: Seems `.Single()` would throw in case I have both  `int Foo(Base arg)` and `int Foo(Derivied arg)` which isn't  well aligned with [overload resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1164-overload-resolution)

Answer (score 12):

The code posted by Mark isn't complete and what ever is there isn't working.

So tweaked and complete.

```
class DoubleDispatch
{
    public T Foo<T>(object arg)
    {
        var method = from m in GetType().GetMethods(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                     where m.Name == "Foo"
                           && m.GetParameters().Length == 1
                           //&& arg.GetType().IsAssignableFrom
                           //                  (m.GetParameters()[0].GetType())
                           &&Type.GetType(m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.FullName).IsAssignableFrom(arg.GetType())
                           && m.ReturnType == typeof(T)
                     select m;


        return (T)method.Single().Invoke(this, new object[] { arg });
    }

    public int Foo(int arg)
    {
        return 10;
    }

    public string Foo(string arg)
    {
        return 5.ToString();
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object x = 5;
        DoubleDispatch dispatch = new DoubleDispatch();

        Console.WriteLine(dispatch.Foo<int>(x));


        Console.WriteLine(dispatch.Foo<string>(x.ToString()));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Thanks Mark and others for nice explanation on Double Dispatcher pattern.

Comment: I agree.  This code is complete and shows what double dispatch really is.  The explanation from mark's answer and this code go perfectly together.

Comment: Wouldn't writing 
    "Console.WriteLine(dispatch.Foo<x.GetType()>(x));"
be a more dynamic and useful way to take advantage of the Pattern?

Answer (score 10):

The other answers use generics and the runtime type system. But to be clear the use of generics and runtime type system doesn't have anything to do with double dispatch.  They can be used to implement it but double dispatch is just dependent on using the concrete type at runtime to dispatch calls.  It's illustrated more clearly I think in [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).  I'll include the translated C++ code below. The key to this is the virtual CollideWith on SpaceShip and that it's overridden on ApolloSpacecraft. This is where the "double" dispatch takes place and the correct asteroid method is called for the given spaceship type.

```
class SpaceShip
{
    public virtual void CollideWith(Asteroid asteroid)
    {
        asteroid.CollideWith(this);
    }
}

class ApolloSpacecraft : SpaceShip
{
    public override void CollideWith(Asteroid asteroid)
    {
        asteroid.CollideWith(this);
    }
}

class Asteroid
{
    public virtual void CollideWith(SpaceShip target)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Asteroid hit a SpaceShip");
    }

    public virtual void CollideWith(ApolloSpacecraft target)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Asteroid hit ApolloSpacecraft");
    }
}

class ExplodingAsteroid : Asteroid
{
    public override void CollideWith(SpaceShip target)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ExplodingAsteroid hit a SpaceShip");
    }

    public override void CollideWith(ApolloSpacecraft target)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ExplodingAsteroid hit ApolloSpacecraft");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Asteroid[] asteroids = new Asteroid[] { new Asteroid(), new ExplodingAsteroid() };

        ApolloSpacecraft spacecraft = new ApolloSpacecraft();

        spacecraft.CollideWith(asteroids[0]);
        spacecraft.CollideWith(asteroids[1]);

        SpaceShip spaceShip = new SpaceShip();

        spaceShip.CollideWith(asteroids[0]);
        spaceShip.CollideWith(asteroids[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You wrote "dependent on using the concrete type at runtime to dispatch calls.". But your realization also depend on static type and the overload resolution in those lines : ` asteroid.CollideWith(this);`. So, additional places  should be changed with introduction of new SpaceShip: adding new Asteroid's `CollideWith` method.

Comment: That is what double dispatch entails - using the runtime type of two objects to dispatch a function call.  The rest of this is all implementation details. There are a variety of ways to implement double dispatch, this answer provides a simple direct example.  Given the question, I thought it appropriate to provide a simple example.

Comment: This is a pretty good intermediate form between OOP and visitor pattern in its pure form. In OOP, adding a new function requires you to change many modules, while in this case, it is a little bit tidier to add more functions like PierceThrough(), and GetIntoOrbit(), but hard to add more Spaceships(you have to add another method to each Asteroid).

Answer (score 8):

C# 4 introduces the pseudo type `dynamic` which resolves the function call at runtime (instead of compile time). (That is, the runtime type of the expression is used). Double- (or multi-dispatch) can be simplified to:

```
class C { }

static void Foo(C x) => Console.WriteLine(nameof(Foo));
static void Foo(object x) => Console.WriteLine(nameof(Object));

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object x = new C();

    Foo((dynamic)x); // prints: "Foo"
    Foo(x);          // prints: "Object"
}
```

Note also by using `dynamic` you prevent the static analyzer of the compiler to examine this part of the code. You should therefore carefully consider the use of `dynamic`.

Answer (score 0):

Full listing of working code

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestConsoleApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int x = 5;
            var dispatch = new DoubleDispatch();

            Console.WriteLine(dispatch.Foo<int>(x));
            Console.WriteLine(dispatch.Foo<string>(x.ToString()));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class DoubleDispatch
    {
        public T Foo<T>(T arg)
        {
            var method = GetType()
                .GetMethods()
                .Single(m =>
                    m.Name == "Foo" &&
                    m.GetParameters().Length == 1 &&
                    arg.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType) &&
                    m.ReturnType == typeof(T));

            return (T) method.Invoke(this, new object[] {arg});
        }

        public int Foo(int arg)
        {
            return arg;
        }

        public string Foo(string arg)
        {
            return arg;
        }
    }
}
```