# How should I refactor a long chain of try-and-catch-wrapped speculative casting operations

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, xsd, try-catch

I have some C# code that walks XML schemata using the Xml.Schema classes from the .NET framework. The various simple type restrictions are abstracted in the framework as a whole bunch of classes derived from Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaFacet. Unless there is something I've missed, the only way to know which of the derived facet types a given facet is, is to speculatively cast it to one of them, catching the resultant InvalidCastOperation in case of failure. Doing this leaves me with a really ugly function like this:

```
private void NavigateFacet(XmlSchemaFacet facet)
{
    try
    {
        handler.Length((XmlSchemaLengthFacet)facet);
    }
    catch(InvalidCastException)
    {
        try
        {
            handler.MinLength((XmlSchemaMinLengthFacet)facet);
        }
        catch(InvalidCastException)
        {
            try
            {
                handler.MaxLength((XmlSchemaMaxLengthFacet)facet);
            }
            catch(InvalidCastException)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I assume there must be more elegant ways to do this; either using some property I've missed from the .NET framework, or with some clever piece of OO trickery. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because I prefer debugging data to debugging code, I'd do it like this, especially if the code had to handle all of the `XmlSchemaFacet` subclasses:

```
Dictionary<Type, Action<XmlSchemaFacet>> HandlerMap = 
   new Dictionary<Type, Action<XmlSchemaFacet>>
{
   {typeof(XmlSchemaLengthFacet), handler.Length},
   {typeof(XmlSchemaMinLengthFacet), handler.MinLength},
   {typeof(XmlSchemaMaxLengthFacet), handler.MaxLength}
};

HandlerMap[facet.GetType()](facet);
```

This'll throw a `KeyNotFoundException` if `facet` isn't of a known type.  Note that all of the handler methods will have to cast their argument from `XmlSchemaFacet`, so you're probably not saving on total lines of code, but you're definitely saving on the number of paths through your code.

There also comes a point where (assuming that the map is pre-built) mapping types to methods with a dictionary will be faster than traversing a linear list of types, which is essentially what using a bunch of `if` blocks gets you.

Comment: I *really* like the look of this. Am trying it out in my code now, will come back to upvote after it's gone in.

Comment: Wow, thanks again for this, it works well and the code is much cleaner now. Also, as you indicate, the new code runs faster. Even though the number of unit tests in the system went up with this change, the time reported by NUnit went down appreciably. If I could upvote more than once, I would. :)

Comment: +1 *much* better than all the other answers here. This is what I was hoping for in my comment on Bevan's answer.

Comment: I like this. One improvement you might consider is initializing this as a field so multiple calls don't have to recreate the dictionary.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: I assume that's what he meant by "assuming the map is pre-built".

Answer (score 6):

You can try using the `as` keyword.  Some others have recommended using the `is` keyword instead.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr/496167#496167) to be a great explanation of why `as` is better.

Some sample code:

```
private void NavigateFacet(XmlSchemaFacet facet)
{
  XmlSchemaLengthFacet lengthFacet = facet as XmlSchemaLengthFacet;
  if (lengthFacet != null)
  {
    handler.Length(lengthFacet);
  }
  else
  {
    // Re-try with XmlSchemaMinLengthFacet, etc.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've upvoted this answer because it definitely was an improvement over my initial mess, but Robert's answer was spectacularly good from a code-cleanliness perspective, so his gets accepted.

Comment: @Matt: see my update on benchmarking `is` vs. `as`. I'd put this in the category of "really doesn't matter".

Answer (score 4):

```
private void NavigateFacet(XmlSchemaFacet facet)
{
    if (facet is XmlSchemaLengthFacet)
    {
        handler.Length((XmlSchemaLengthFacet)facet);
    }
    else if (facet is XmlSchemaMinLengthFacet)
    {
        handler.MinLength((XmlSchemaMinLengthFacet)facet);
    }
    else if (facet is XmlSchemaMaxLengthFacet)
    {
        handler.MinLength((XmlSchemaMaxLengthFacet)facet);
    }

    // etc.
}
```

**Update**:  I decided to benchmark the different methods discussed here (`is` vs. `as`).  Here is the code that I used:

```
object c1 = new Class1();
int trials = 10000000;
Class1 tester;
Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < trials; i++)
{
    if (c1 is Class1)
    {
        tester = (Class1)c1;
    }
}
watch.Stop(); 
MessageBox.Show(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()); // ~104 ms 
watch.Reset();
watch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < trials; i++)
{
    tester = c1 as Class1;
    if (tester != null)
    {
        // 
    }
}
watch.Stop(); 
MessageBox.Show(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()); // ~86 ms
watch.Reset();
watch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < trials; i++)
{
    if (c1 is Class1)
    {
        // 
    }
}
watch.Stop();     
MessageBox.Show(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()); // ~74 ms
watch.Reset();
watch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < trials; i++)
{
    //
}
watch.Stop();     
MessageBox.Show(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()); // ~50 ms
```

As expected, using the `as` keyword and then checking for null *is* faster than using the `is` keyword and casting (36 ms vs. 54 ms, subtracting the cost of the loop itself).

**However**, using the `is` keyword and then *not* casting is faster still (24ms), which means that finding the correct type with a series of `is` checks and then only casting once when the correct type is identified *could* actually be faster (depending upon the number of different type checks that have to be done in this method before the correct type is identified).

The deeper point, however, is that the number of trials in this test is 10 *million,* which means it really doesn't make much difference which method you use.  Using `is` and casting takes 0.0000054 milliseconds, while using `as` and checking for null takes 0.0000036 milliseconds (on my ancient notebook).

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, I've upvoted this, but Robert gets the accepted answer for his solution below.

Comment: @Phil: no problem, I like his answer better, too.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the `as` keyword - if the cast fails, you get a `null` instead of an exception.

```
private void NavigateFacet(XmlSchemaFacet facet)
{
    var length = facet as XmlSchemaLengthFacet;
    if (length != null)
    {
        handler.Length(length);
        return;
    }

    var minlength = facet as XmlSchemaMinLengthFacet;
    if (minlength != null)
    {
        handler.MinLength(minlength);
        return;
    }

    var maxlength = facet as XmlSchemaMaxLengthFacet;
    if (maxlength != null)
    {
        handler.MaxLength(maxlength);
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

If you had control over the classes, I'd suggest using a variant of the Visitor pattern (aka [Double Despatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587/double-dispatch-in-c) to recover the type information more cleanly, but since you don't, this is one relatively simple approach.

**Update**: Using the variable to store the result of the `as` cast avoids the need to go through the type checking logic twice.

**Update 2**: When C# 4 becomes available, you'll be able to use `dynamic` to do the dispatching for you:

```
public class HandlerDemo 
{
    public void Handle(XmlSchemaLengthFacet facet) { ... }
    public void Handle(XmlSchemaMinLengthFacet facet) { ... }
    public void Handle(XmlSchemaMaxLengthFacet facet) { ... }
    ...
}

private void NavigateFacet(XmlSchemaFacet facet)
{
    dynamic handler = new HandlerDemo();
    handler.Handle(facet);
}
```

This will work because method dispatch on dynamic objects uses the same rules as normal method overriding, but evaluated at run-time instead of compile-time.

Under the hood, the Dynamic Language Runtime (DLR) will be doing much the same kind of trick as the code shown in this (and other answers), but with the addition of caching for performance.

Comment: Do you really prefer this to mine or MusiGenesis's answer?

Comment: Personally, I don't like *any* of the answers here (including mine).  Either you have to type each Type twice, or you have to type the Type and do a check for null for each Type.  All you're really doing in this method is associating each Type with a particular method in `handler` (whatever that is) - there must be a cleaner LINQ-y way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a proper way to do this without any try-catches.

```
if (facet is XmlSchemaLengthFacet)
{
    handler.Length((XmlSchemaLengthFacet)facet); 
} 
else if (facet is XmlSchemaMinLengthFacet)
{
    handler.MinLength((XmlSchemaMinLengthFacet)facet); 
} 
else if (facet is XmlSchemaMaxLengthFacet)
{
    handler.MaxLength((XmlSchemaMaxLengthFacet)facet); 
} 
else
{
    //Handle Error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- use "is" to determine whether an object is of a given type
- use "as" for type conversion, it is faster than normal casting and won't throw exceptions, it reuturns null on error instead

You can do it like this:

```
private void NavigateFacet(XmlSchemaFacet facet)
{
  if (facet is XmlSchemaLengthFacet)
  {
        handler.Length(facet as XmlSchemaLengthFacet);
  }
  else if (facet is XmlSchemaMinLengthFacet)
  {
        handler.MinLength(facet as XmlSchemaMinLengthFacet);
  }
  else if (facet is XmlSchemaMaxLengthFacet)
  {
       handler.MaxLength(facet as XmlSchemaMaxLengthFacet);
  }
}
```

Comment: I prefer to use "as" and check for != null - that way, the object in question has to be inspected (by reflection) only once, and the code is still totally fail safe.

Comment: Using both "is" and "as" is redundant. I'd use either Bevan's solution (more efficient) or MusiGenesis's solution (simpler) instead.