# Is it possible to make an abstract method's parameter list have overridable length and types?

Tags: c#, parameters, methods, overriding

Is it possible to create a base class like the following:

```
 public abstract class baseClass
{
     public abstract void SetParameters(/*want this to be adjustable*/);
}
```

so that classes that override it can define the parameters required?
In other words, I want to force the method to be overridden, but leave it up to the overriding class what is required here - so one might be

```
 public class derivedClass1 : baseClass
{
     public override void SetParameters(Point a, int b);
}
```

whereas another could be

```
 public class derivedClass2 : baseClass
{
     public override void SetParameters(List<Line> a, Point b, Point c, bool e);
}
```

?

Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: Did you mean to say `public class derivedClass : baseClass` in the last two examples?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I will change that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Absolutely not - that would break half the point of having the abstract method in the first place - no-one would be able to call it, because they wouldn't know which method signature had actually been written. The whole point of an abstract class is that a client can have a reference of type `BaseClass` without caring about what the type of the actual implementation is.

If the base class is able to predict in advance which types might be involved, one possibility to make life easier for the caller is to have the most general signature (typically the one with the most parameters) abstract, and make various overloads which *call* that general one providing defaults for the parameters that the client hasn't specified.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done IF the parameters were all set to the same type and in the same number i guess (not sure if you can use params T[], but if its possible, then you can adjust it too). You can achieve by using Generics, like @simonalexander2005 said

```
public abstract class baseClass<T> where T : class
{
     public abstract T SetParameters(params T[] parameters);
}
```

its up to you to decide how many parameters the derived class will use. But, im not sure if its a good practice...

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. An overriding method needs to match the parameters exactly—it's the same as implementing an interface. You may be interested in the [double-dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587/double-dispatch-in-c) pattern.

Comment: The link you gave seems to do it for one variable-type parameter (in which case you may as well use <T>?) - but not for a variable number of variable-type parameters... or am I misreading it?

Comment: You would have to change the example to accommodate a `params object[] args` parameter list.