# How to Downcast to an Overloaded Method

Tags: c#, relationship, downcast

I have a slight problem in my code here I think is interesting:

```
foreach(ISceneNode node in (root as IGroupNode))
            {
                PreVisit(node);
                if (notFound == false)
                {
                    return node;
                }
                else
                    PostVisit(node);
            }
```

I'm trying to call the methods PreVisit and PostVisit on the ISceneNode object node, which is a parent class to other types of nodes.  However, because this is "too general" of an object relationship, I am not allowed to call the methods:

```
//methods
void PreVisit(IDrawableNode drawable)
    {
        string targetName = drawable.Name;
        Boolean notFound = true;
        CompareToTarget(targetName, notFound, drawable);
    }

    void PreVisit(ITransformNode transform)
    {
        string targetName = transform.Name;
        Boolean notFound = true;
        CompareToTarget(targetName, notFound, transform);
    }

    void PreVisit(IStateNode state)
    {
        string targetName = state.Name;
        Boolean notFound = true;
        CompareToTarget(targetName, notFound, state);
    }

    void PreVisit(IGroupNode group)
    {
        string targetName = group.Name;
        Boolean notFound = true;
        CompareToTarget(targetName, notFound, group);
    }
```

The IGroupNode, IStateNode, etc derive from the ISceneNode... so why can't I call this overloaded method using just an ISceneNode?  Is it because it doesn't know which method to select?  How can I account for this in my code and workaround it?

Comment: This is called multiple- (or dynamic-) dispatch.  You need a visitor pattern.

Comment: I do have a visitor pattern.

Comment: Mind explaining further?  This is actually the implementation of the SearchVisitor class, which performs a search on a tree of these nodes.

Comment: How about you typecast the parameter to required type? PreVisit(((IGroupNode)node));

Comment: If you make `node` a dynamically-typed variable, the runtime will automatically select the best-matching overload, or throw an exception if none matches: `foreach (dynamic node in (group as IGroupNode))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call your method, the object is ISceneNode, as you did not define a PreVisit(ISceneNode), it will fail to find a suitable method.

The compiler will not be able to understand that you already defined a subcase for each subtype. One solution would be to cast it to check if your object implement one of the sub interfaces and call the method on the casted object.

Of course, this is not really a good solution to just write this in the middle of the rest of the code. As SLaks mention you should use a dispatch, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587/double-dispatch-in-c), or using C# 4.0 keyword `dynamic` as shown [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/04/05/visitor-and-multiple-dispatch-via-c-dynamic.aspx)

Here is the example of the second link:

```
class Animal 
{ 
}

class Cat : Animal 
{ 
}

class Dog : Animal 
{ 
}
```

Here are the specialisations:

```
void ReactSpecialization(Animal me, Animal other) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not interested in {1}.", me, other); 
}

void ReactSpecialization(Cat me, Dog other) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Cat runs away from dog."); 
}

void ReactSpecialization(Dog me, Cat other) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Dog chases cat."); 
}
```

Now this is how you define the double dispatch in C# 4.0 using `dynamic`:

```
void React(Animal me, Animal other) 
{ 
    ReactSpecialization(me as dynamic, other as dynamic); 
}
```

Then run

```
void Test() 
{ 
    Animal cat = new Cat(); 
    Animal dog = new Dog(); 

    React(cat, dog); 
    React(dog, cat); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# `dynamic` does that nicely:

```
PreVisit((dynamic)node);
```

That select the appropriate method at runtime using C# semantics.

Comment: But since the implementations are all the same, that's better done by using inheritance, I think. Just declare a method called `PreVisit(ISceneNode)`. The method itself can then call virtual overloads, if needed.

Comment: @PMF the node class itself would have to have a virtual method to benefit from virtual dispatch. That would work, yes. But that means that the all subclasses must adhere to that protocol and know what a visitor is. I'd prefer the node class not to know the concept of visiting nodes.

Comment: Ok, then you could of course write your visitor methods using templatized arguments or using extension methods.