# Pass more-derived type (via 'this') in less-derived method to overloaded method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, this, parametric-polymorphism

Simple hierarchy, 3 levels and with a shared/single dependency to a class with overloaded methods that differ only by type signature:

[image]

When viewed in a debugger, the type of 'this' in Derived.Bar is the instantiated/concrete Double-Derived.

The below works as expected ONLY because of the **(dynamic)** cast. Remove it and you'll see that the overload resolution uses the calling class rather than the concrete class.

Curious if there's a 'purer' way of it working as expected without the performance hit of DLR (or some other reflection-based alternative):

```
public class PolymorphicConsumer
{
    public void Foo(Base caller)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Its all about the base.");
    }

    public void Foo(Derived caller)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Its all about the Derived.");
    }

    public void Foo(DoubleDerived caller)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Its all about the Double-Derived.");
    }

}

public abstract class Base
{
    protected PolymorphicConsumer _dep;
    public Base (PolymorphicConsumer dep)
    {
        _dep = dep;
    }
    public virtual void Bar()
    {
        // No impl.
    }

}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived(PolymorphicConsumer dep):base(dep)
    { }

    public override void Bar()
    {
        _dep.Foo((dynamic)this);            
    }
}

public class DoubleDerived : Derived
{
    public DoubleDerived(PolymorphicConsumer dep):base(dep)
    { }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dd = new DoubleDerived(new PolymorphicConsumer());

        dd.Bar();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double dispatch in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587/double-dispatch-in-c)

Comment: Having that kind of overload in itself feels like a bit of a design smell. I'm curious about the actual use case.

Comment: There's conflicting advice on the design: https://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2010/04/19/double-dispatch-is-a-code-smell/ 
**vs**
https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/03/30/strengthening-your-domain-the-double-dispatch-pattern/

Thanks @dsolimano for the link, which at least one of these is sourced from. Will close as a dupe...