# Casting object to type variable inside method

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, types

I have the below extension method where I pass the type and cast the object to the type but get a compile error at casting.

```
public static void AddCellProperties(this ColumnInfo _columnInfo, Type type)
{
    _columnInfo.SetCellUsing((c, o) =>
               {
                   if (o == null) c.SetCellValue("NULL");
                   else c.SetCellValue((type)o); // getting an error here near "type"
               })
               .SetPropertyUsing(a => a as string == "NULL" ? null : Convert.ChangeType(a, type, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

But whereas this works.

```
public static void AddCellProperties(this ColumnInfo _columnInfo)
{
    _columnInfo.SetCellUsing((c, o) =>
               {
                   if (o == null) c.SetCellValue("NULL");
                   else c.SetCellValue((int)o);
               })
               .SetPropertyUsing(a => a as string == "NULL" ? null : Convert.ChangeType(a, typeof(int), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

I am just trying to replace the `int` with `type` so that caller can pass whatever type.

Could anyone please let me know how I can overcome this issue? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: `SetCellValue` is a generic method?

Comment: @Eldar, nope it's not a generic method

Comment: So what is the signature of it?

Comment: its just `void SetCellValue(int value);`

Comment: If it is how can a user pass whatever type?

Comment: @Eldar It's has same method with different parameters kind of overloading

Comment: Ideally, you'd clarify that with [edit] of the post... You probably asking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587/double-dispatch-in-c (if not - make sure to clarify that too as part of the edit).

Comment: Rather than passing Type, why not use generics and pass a type of <T>

Comment: @scottdavidwalker I'm pretty sure OP is asking about "select method based on type" (like `dynamic`) rather than generalizing all methods to be the same - waiting for to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot typecast using your `type` variable in this manner.  That is why you are getting an error on the line you have commented.  If the type expected by `SetCellValue` is always `int` then it doesn't really make sense to try to typecast it to `type` since it is expecting `int`.  Instead, use the same `Convert.ChangeType` method.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that T could be any type, not simply int. If any of those types would produce a compile time error, you'll see it.

This article explains in more detail: https://ericlippert.com/2015/10/14/casts-and-type-parameters-do-not-mix/#more-2852

Are you sure you want to be able to pass in any generic type to cast your data to? Will your data cleanly cast to any type provided?