How to refactor this type-dependant code to avoid downcasting?
Background
I am coding in Unity, with C#8.0.
I am making a game where the player battles enemies by playing cards that have different effects (think Slay the Spire). The player selects the card, then selects the card's target, and then (if the target is valid) the card's effect is invoked.
Lots of different game objects can be the target of a card: enemies, the player character, other cards, the turn counter, the sky, etc. For each object that can be a target I have its class implement an interface:
public interface ICardTarget
{
    public bool IsValidTarget(Card targetingCard);
}

Similarly, lots of different game objects can play cards: the player character, enemies, obstacle objects, etc. For each object that can use a card I have its class implement an interface:
public interface ICardUser
{
    //I don't have anything in here, this is really more of just a tag to group together any card users. Am I using interfaces right?
}

So some of the objects in my scene might be:
public class Enemy : ICardTarget, ICardUser
{
    public bool IsValidTarget(Card targetingCard) {/*...*/}

    public string Species {get;set;}
}

public class PlayerCharacter : ICardTarget, ICardUser
{
    public bool IsValidTarget(Card targetingCard) {/*...*/}

    public float AttackSpeed {get;set;}
    public int Health {get;set;}
}

public class Weather : ICardTarget
{
    public bool IsValidTarget(Card targetingCard) {/*...*/}

    public bool IsCloudy {get;set;}
}

public class Boulder: ICardUser
{
    public int Mass {get;set;}
}

etc.
Each card defines which types of targets are valid. When the player (or any card user for that matter) selects an object as the card's target, the card passes itself to the IsValidTarget function and receives a bool response as to whether this is a valid target for this card.
public class Card
{
    private ICardUser _user;     //reference to this card's user, set somewhere else
    private ICardTarget _target; //reference to this card's target, set somewhere else

    public void CheckTarget()
    {
        if (_target.IsValidTarget(this))
        {
            PerformCardEffect();
        }
    }

    private void PerformCardEffect() {/*whatever the card does*/}
}

So far so good! Now the card needs to perform its effect on the targeted object, and also may have an effect on the card's user.
The Problem
Currently, the only thing the card knows about this targeted object is that it is a valid target (that's all that the ICardTarget interface guarantees, after all). So how do I perform the card's effect that depends on the type of the target without checking the type and downcasting?
The exact same problem applies to the card user: all I know is that the card came from a card user, how can I interact with it without downcasting?
Or is downcasting not the boogieman I think it is?
Attempted Solution 1
I don't worry about it and downcast the target/user to one of the classes that implements it when PerformCardEffect() is run:
public class Card
{
    private ICardUser _user;
    private ITarget _target;

    public PerformCardEffect()
    {
        if (_target is Weather w)
        {
            w.IsCloudy = true;
        }
        if (_target is Enemy e)
        {
            print(e.Species);
        }
        if (_target is PlayerCharacter p)
        {
            p.AttackSpeed *= 2;
        }

       if (_user is PlayerCharacter p)
        {
            p.Health -= 3;
        }
       if (_user is Enemy e)
        {
            e.Health -= 5;
        }

        //etc.
    }
}

This is easiest for me to iterate on right now, but I know this is frowned upon.
Attempted Solution 2
I modify ICardTarget/ICardUser so that the responsibility of calling the correct function is moved off of Card and onto them:
public interface ICardTarget
{
    //...
    public void SelectCardEffectTarget(Card targetingCard);
    //...
}

public interface ICardUser
{
    public void SelectCardEffectUser(Card targetingCard);
}

public class Enemy : ICardTarget, ICardUser
{
    //...
    public void SelectCardEffectTarget(Card targetingCard)
    {
        targetingCard.PerformCardEffectTarget(this);
    }

    public void SelectCardEffectUser(Card targetingCard)
    {
        targetingCard.PerformCardEffectUser(this);
    }
    //...
}

public class PlayerCharacter : ICardTarget, ICardUser
{
    //...
    public void SelectCardEffectTarget(Card targetingCard)
    {
        targetingCard.PerformCardEffectTarget(this);
    }

    public void SelectCardEffectUser(Card targetingCard)
    {
        targetingCard.PerformCardEffectUser(this);
    }
    //...
}

public class Weather : ICardTarget
{
    //...
    public void SelectCardEffectTarget(Card targetingCard)
    {
        targetingCard.PerformCardEffectTarget(this);
    }
    //...
}

public class Card
{
    private ICardUser _user;
    private ITarget _target;

    public void CheckTarget()
    {
        if (_target.IsValidTarget(this))
        {
            _target.SelectCardEffectTarget(this);
            _user.SelectCardEffectUser(this);
        }
    }


    public void PerformCardEffectTarget(Weather w)
    {
        w.IsCloudy = true;
    }
    public void PerformCardEffectTarget(Enemy e)
    {
        print(e.Species);
    }
    public void PerformCardEffectTarget(PlayerCharacter p)
    {
        p.AttackSpeed *= 2;
    }

    public void PerformCardEffectUser(Enemy e)
    {
        e.Health -= 5;
    }
    public void PerformCardEffectUser(PlayerCharacter p)
    {
        p.Health -= 3;
    }

    //I have to include these calls so that any objects not caught by the above overloaded parameters default to doing nothing.
    public void PerformCardEffectTarget(ICardTarget t) {}
    public void PerformCardEffectUser(ICardUser u) {}
}

This seems better but there's a lot of passing references back and forth, which isn't a bad thing but to me it feels a little excessive. I also have to expose a lot of methods on both Card and the interfaces.
P.S. Is there a shorter way of writing SelectCardEffectTarget()/SelectCardEffectUser() so that I don't have to repeat the same code block in each subclass? I know I could make ICardTarget/ICardUser into a class and set the function there so it's inherited, but that doesn't seem like the appropriate hierarchy for this situation.
Attempted Solution 3 (Failed)
I tried to utilize a generic class to specify the target/user types, but I couldn't figure out a way to involve it and get useful functionality from it.
public class CardEffectDetails<T,U> where T : ICardTarget where U : ICardUser
{
    T Target {get;set;}
    U User {get;set;}
}

public class Card
{
    private ICardTarget _target;
    private ICardUser _user;

    private void CreateEffectDetails()
    {
        CardEffectDetails<_target.GetType(), _user.GetType()> effectDetails = new();
        //what can I even do with this thing?
    }
}


CardEffectDetails<_target.GetType(), _user.GetType()> yeah that's not how generics work ;) the generic types have to be known at compile time

what speaks against doing the type check? You could use a switch which would probably be better than using individual if checks (especially without using else if)

What you're trying to do is called "double dispatch" a special case of "multiple dispatch"). C# doesn't support this natively (although the dynamic keyword can help a bit, but generally the use of that is discouraged). This might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587/double-dispatch-in-c

Also see this excellent Eric Lippert article

Question, if possible: what would be the problem with ICardTarget exposing what kind of target it is (maybe with an TargetType enum)? Instead of then checking the type, you can check the enum property ensured by the interface

@derHugo I was trying to explore my options of doing things without type-checking, since so many resources claim how "non-OO" type-checking approaches tend to be. If this is one of those scenarios where type-checking is most appropriate, that's fine by me, but I wanted to make sure I was approaching this from all angles before committing to a solution.

@derHugo Dang :) I suppose everything looked like a nail when I got the hammer of "learning what generics are".

@Pedro Costa I see, so you're saying I should have a public TargetTypeEnum GetType() function in the interface, then the card would call that function to get what type of object this target is and can act accordingly from there? I don't see how that's too much different than just checking the type of the target at that point (because once I know the enum I will still need to cast the target into its appropriate type to reference its members), but am I wrong about your suggestion?

@Will I would have suggested a property, not a function (interfaces can expose properties).
Whether you'd need to cast after or not, well, not necessarily. If you can keep behaviour inside interfaces and outside of concrete implementations you could potentially avoid ever needing to cast - but don't take my word for it, I probably have as much if not less experience than you in this.
EDIT: my explanation was a bit confusing, but in Eric Lippert's article, namely separating object state from game rules, you can kind of understand what I mean

@PedroCosta Regarding that article, I struggle to visualize a concrete example. Is this what he's saying:
Now I have this "rulebook" class public static class CardRulebook with a method public static AttemptEffect(Card card, ICardTarget target, ICardUser user). When a card needs to perform its effect, it simply calls CardRulebook.AttemptEffect(this, _target, _user), not worrying about the specific _target/_user types. The rulebook then chooses the appropriate action (which could be no action). Doesn't the rulebook still need to get the types to choose the proper rule?

Not necessarily - I would argue making a class for every single card would be excessive - maybe you can separate by a supposed card type - but that's not the point.
In fact, the rulebook holding what the cards do could be a way out of this - provided the card has a way to identify itself. And then you don't need to cast the card, it's enough for the rulebook to know which card is being played, who plays it and against who.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

If you read this Eric Lippert article on this subject he ends up recommending a rules-based approach.
This pushes the logic for playing a card onto a target into a class that is responsible for tying the logic together. Let's have a go at that. (This will be a somewhat simplified version for brevity.)
First let's define some basic interfaces that we will need:
public interface ITarget
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public interface ICard : ITarget
{
}

(Obviously a real application would expand these somewhat.)
Next, we can write a "rules collection" which will encapsulate and hide any reflection and will manage a collection of rules for playing a card on a target:
public sealed class RulesCollection
{
    public void AddRule<TCard, TTarget>(Action<TCard, TTarget> play) where TCard : ICard where TTarget : ITarget
    {
        string key = keyFromTypes(typeof(TCard), typeof(TTarget));
        _rules.Add(key, (card, target) => play((TCard)card, (TTarget)target));
    }

    public bool IsValidTarget(ICard card, ITarget target)
    {
        string key = keyFromObjects(card, target);
        return _rules.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public void PlayCard(ICard card, ITarget target)
    {
        string key = keyFromObjects(card, target);

        if (_rules.TryGetValue(key, out var play))
            play(card, target);
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{card.Name} cannot be played on {target.Name}");
    }

    static string keyFromObjects(ICard card, ITarget target)
    {
        return keyFromTypes(card.GetType(), target.GetType());
    }

    static string keyFromTypes(Type cardType, Type targetType)
    {
        return cardType.FullName + "|" + targetType.FullName;
    }

    delegate void playDelegate(ICard card, ITarget target);

    readonly Dictionary<string, playDelegate> _rules = new Dictionary<string, playDelegate>();
}

(This class only handles two types - the card type and the target type. However, you can easily extend it to handle more types for more complex interactions.)
Now let's define some concrete game object types:
public sealed class Fireball : ICard
{
    public int Damage { get; set; } = 10;

    public string Name => "Fireball";
}

public sealed class Hurricane : ICard
{
    public string Name => "Hurricane";

    public int WindSpeed => 90;
    public int Rain      => 100;
}

public sealed class Player : ITarget
{
    public int    Health { get; set; } = 100;
    public string Name   => "Player";
}

public sealed class Enemy : ITarget
{
    public int    Health { get; set; } = 50;
    public string Name   => "Enemy";
}

public sealed class Weather : ITarget
{
    public string Name => "Weather";

    public int WindSpeed { get; set; } = 5;
    public int Rain      { get; set; } = 0;
}

Now we can create a class which actually implements all the necessary card rules and uses a RulesCollection to store them:
public sealed class RulesManager
{
    public RulesManager()
    {
        _rules.AddRule<Fireball, Player>(fireballPlayer);
        _rules.AddRule<Fireball, Enemy>(fireballEnemy);
        _rules.AddRule<Hurricane, Weather>(hurricaneWeather);
    }

    public bool IsValidTarget(ICard card, ITarget target) => _rules.IsValidTarget(card, target);
    public void PlayCard     (ICard card, ITarget target) => _rules.PlayCard     (card, target);

    static void hurricaneWeather(Hurricane hurricane, Weather weather)
    {
        weather.Rain      = hurricane.Rain;
        weather.WindSpeed = hurricane.WindSpeed;

        Console.WriteLine($"Hurricane set weather wind speed to {hurricane.WindSpeed} and rain to {hurricane.Rain}");
    }

    static void fireballPlayer(Fireball fireball, Player player)
    {
        player.Health -= fireball.Damage;
        Console.WriteLine($"Fireball damages player for {fireball.Damage}. Player health is now {player.Health}");
    }

    static void fireballEnemy(Fireball fireball, Enemy enemy)
    {
        enemy.Health -= fireball.Damage;
        Console.WriteLine($"Fireball damages enemy for {fireball.Damage}. Enemy health is now {enemy.Health}");
    }

    readonly RulesCollection _rules = new RulesCollection();
}

You should be able to see how to extend this this cover all your card interactions.
Finally we can exercise the rules:
public static void Main()
{
    var rules = new RulesManager();

    var player    = new Player();
    var fireball  = new Fireball();
    var hurricane = new Hurricane();
    var weather   = new Weather();
    var enemy     = new Enemy();

    rules.PlayCard(fireball, player);
    rules.PlayCard(fireball, enemy);
    rules.PlayCard(hurricane, weather);

    Console.WriteLine(rules.IsValidTarget(hurricane, weather)); // Prints "true".
    Console.WriteLine(rules.IsValidTarget(hurricane, player));  // Prints "false".

    rules.PlayCard(fireball, weather); // Throws exception with message "Fireball cannot be played on Weather". 
}


See this DotNetFiddle for a runnable example:
The output of this is:
Fireball damages player for 10. Player health is now 90
Fireball damages enemy for 10. Enemy health is now 40
Hurricane set weather wind speed to 90 and rain to 100
True
False
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Fireball cannot be played on Weather
   at RulesCollection.PlayCard(ICard card, ITarget target)
   at RulesManager.PlayCard(ICard card, ITarget target)
   at Net48Console.Program.Main()


Ah, thank you so much for this! I had not really grokked what Lippert was getting at with his rules approach as a class, but your concrete example is excellent!

I did have another question, but first some background:
Here's a fork of your Fiddle where I added a new interface IUser : ITarget to represent the card's user. I updated the rules-related classes to support the ability to involve this user data in the rule effect (so now rules take in <ICard, IUser, ITarget>). I also created a new class, FireEnemy : Enemy, to demonstrate how a card user might affect the card function (i.e. FireEnemy deals extra damage to targets when it uses Fireball).
[QUESTION IN NEXT COMMENT]

My question: how do I handle the default case? That is, what if I don't care what (non-FireEnemy) user is using Fireball? Fireball doesn't reference its user's data at all, so any IUser can use it. I can't seem to create a rule <Fireball, IUser, Player> that all IUsers default to, I have to create a rule for each implementing class of IUser (<Fireball, Player, Player> and <Fireball, Enemy, Player>).
Similarly, what if in the future I add a new interface IHasHealth that Player and Enemy both implement? Ideally I could just add <Fireball, IUser, IHasHealth>.

I understand that both Cards and Users can be targetable, as both of them implement ITarget. but if IUser does not show behaviour itself why have it at all? It seems like IUser (I personally might rename this to ICardUser to be more explicit) could have the behaviour you're looking for. What if an ICardUser requires you to announce what kind of user it is? Is it the Player? an Enemy? A FireEnemy? If you do this, then you have an interface that exposes the properties you require and that will inevitably be set in the implementions Player, Enemy, etc.

As a sidenote - you considered the name of the type to be the way to identify the kind of entity (user) you are referring to, but I would posit that the name of the class should portray not the kind of entity, but how said entity implemented its behaviours (an enemy behaves like an enemy, and it's its behaviour that makes it an enemy, not its type)

@Will: It gets a bit more fiddly to handle multiple types with defaults like you want - you have to change things to store keys for different combinations of types. I don't have time to do anything just now but I'll try to demo some code tomorrow.

@PedroCosta I suppose you are right that IUser is not strictly necessary. Since we are now defining valid type combinations for a card effect via the rulebook, it's not the type that is limiting which entities can play cards but the rules we defined. ITarget in this context has really become more of "the fundamental class that card rules interact upon", not strictly only the target of a card anymore (perhaps a better suited name might be ICardInteractable).
Regarding your suggestion for renaming the classes, could you give an example? I can't quite wrap my head around what you mean.

@Will Here's a modified version of your fork which allows the omission of either the IUser or the ITarget parameters.  The main changes are in RulesCollection which now generates keys allowing for missing parameters.

@Will for me IUser can be usable, provided it has its own behaviour - if it has no behaviour then it is not necessary. If implementing IUser requires the class to declare what kind of user it is, then it does have a reason to exist, as then you can know what kind of user it is without ever casting the object to a certain type.
I would prefer this approach - as far as I can see this would allow a single method to receive a user and a target without defaults for specific types - the rule can be chosen based on the IUser or ITarget object properties

@MatthewWatson Wow, thank you! I feel so silly for not realizing I could simply overload AddRule() and pass in dummy null values, good solution! I realize now, however, that what I want (being able to AddRule<ICard, IUser, IBase>() and have any target classes that implements IBase match this rule) won't work with this current system. This similar system, based on the Lippert article, may serve me better as it checks all rules and simply adds any matches to the effect list, allowing for the aforementioned functionality I want.

At this point, due to the requirement of being able to target so much with cards and the effect of the cards relying on any arbitrary combination of target and user, I may be better off just going with a variation of Attempted Solution 1 from my original post: I'd have a library of functions that each perform a common game action (e.g., DamageTarget(int value, ITarget target), HealUser(int value, IUser user), etc.) that cards can compose together, and any casting occurs in those functions (e.g. in DamageTarget(): if (target is IHasHealth h): ...).

@MatthewWatson If you can think of a way to implement the level of polymorphic matching I want (i.e. using the above example from my comment: have any classes implementing IBase match that rule without having to specify each class with its own rule) using your dictionary rulebook approach, let me know! I'll be working on this problem for the foreseeable future, so any ideas would be immensely helpful. I also want to express how grateful I am for what you have provided so far. I think I might add an addendum to my original post compiling your ideas and summarizing these comments.

@Will I think I liked your scenario a bit too much so I ended up trying to tackle your idea as well :) I will leave you with my fiddle - at the very least I hope it transmits some ideas.

@PedroCosta Thank you, that's awesome! I finally understand what you were saying about combining IUser with ITarget in my original post, now that I see the distinctions you made between IUser and ITarget in your code example. So to summarize: the Traits property provides a way to get type-agnostic data for a target/user (so no need to create or implement IFireResistant, for example, just add the proper enum to the list); any type-checking is performed within the PerformAction method; method overloading is not used for determining types, just if (x is type t) logic.

Thinking out loud, but this message is too big for a comment anyway. Plus, the question is also kinda abstract =)
Option 1 (not your case, I think, but still)
You can make a unified interface with which your effects can interact. It worked well for me in the case of characters (atk, def, hp, mana, evasion, crit chance, etc.), but it doesn't look like a valid option if your objects are too different. However, it can be an option if you only have 5-10 parameters to set up.
Option 2 (boxing, ofc, but it can be ok many cases)
It is almost the same as Option 1, but with Dictionary<string, object> as a container for your parameters. You can place whatever you want there, and your effects can try to get any needed parameters. In that case, your effect would rely not on the type of the card but mostly on the presence of the required parameters for this effect to be applied.

Also, I highly recommend thinking about moving your effects outside of your card. Then, your card's common logic will be mostly like a container with a set of parameters to be changed and set effects to be applied on use.

Thanks for the suggestions!
Regarding "moving your effects outside the card", could you elaborate? Are you saying I should make a class just to hold the effects of a card (let's say CardEffect with a public method Perform(ICardTarget t, ICardUser u)? Then the Card object just holds a reference to the appropriate CardEffect? (so in Card, private CardEffect _effect;, and then call _effect.Perform(_target, _user) when I need to?)

Yeah, something like that. Actually, you can even have a list of those effects. The logic will remain almost the same. Doing this will open the way to have some config and create new cards "on the fly" by combination of name/stats/image if needed/active effects/ etc.

The only thing I would suggest also thinking about is the difference between the target and the user. In my mind, it should be just a source and target of the same type. However, that may not be true for your case.

Users of cards and targets of cards are two different groups: there can be overlap (e.g. a Player can both use and be the target of cards), but some objects might only exist in one group (e.g. the Weather can't use cards, but users can target the Weather). Hence why I am keeping them as separate interfaces instead of just making one ICardUserTarget interface. If I did combine them into one interface, I would need to include things like IsValidTarget() on objects that might never be targets.
Is this what you're getting at, or am I misunderstanding?

If it fits your game design - it can be ok. I just prefer personally to have something more common that can be configured. Game design sometimes can change in really crazy ways)
